# extract_sentiment_terms() function outputs "<chr [0]>" instead of actual word behind character

Tags: r

I am trying basic sentiment analysis steps with the sentimentr package, following the steps at https://towardsdatascience.com/sentiment-analysis-in-r-good-vs-not-good-handling-negations-2404ec9ff2ae.

Running the extract_sentiment_terms() function with simple random text

```
'My life has become terrible since I met you and lost money' %>% extract_sentiment_terms()
```

is expected to output "terrible, lost" in the negative column and "money" in the positive column.
However, when I run the exact same code,

```
<chr [2]>
```

is displayed for negative and

```
<chr [1]>
```

for positive.

It seems like the count of the respective negative and positive words is output instead of the actual values, i.e. words behind.

I highly would appreciate any help to fix this problem, thanks!

Comment: I get the output the medium author gets in the console. Have you tried assigning the code to an object? It outputs a one row df with the relevant information.

Comment: @VictorNautica Thank you for your reply. I found that when running the code in an .rmd file the correct output is display in the console, however not in the output table itself. There still the  <chr [2]>  is displayed.